# How to pass multiple files in one stream to process them pipe-like (without saving) on the receiving side?

Tags: shell, files, streams

I need to determine the filetype on an indeterminate number of base64-encoded filestreams coming from stdin (image files base64-encoded and cat'ed).

A single file would simply be `... | base64 -d | identify -`.

The issue for multiple files is determing the EOF for each file in the stream.  Even if I separate the files with `\004` before sending them to stdout, the receiving end of the pipe (`identify` or `file`, et al) appear not to recognise there is more than one file in the stream (yes, I know the stream is *one* file, but I was hoping en EOF mid-stream would somehow, for various values of "somehow", work.

I've tried reading stdin in a `while read REPLY` loop, but `read` is line-based, not file-based, so appears to not work as I want.

[edit, later]  There is between 3-10 files all less than 400KB, so size and processing isn't an issue for my use case, but I'm interested in the question generally.

[eidt, later]  I'm trying to avoid tmp files (which is my current solution), mainly because I'm philosophically opposed to using the filesystem as a buffer between two adjacent processes when an inter-process stream is much more efficient.  I know that sounds pompous, so for a solution that needs to work right now of course I use tmp files.  However, I realised there is a gap in my knowledge and I'm trying to find the answer for the general case.

Comment: Did you try changing `read`'s line delimiter?

Comment: How large are the images? I wonder if it makes sense to `read` them in all at once, or if something smarter should be done.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams & ikkachu :    edits with more information

Answer (score 1):

It does sort of work if you pipe the input to `while read` with the delimiter set to `\004` (using the `$'...'` expansion, since `read` doesn't interpret backslash escapes)

```
for x in *.jpg ; do base64 < "$x" ; echo -e '\004';  done | 
    while read -rd $'\004' file ; do 
        echo "$file" | base64 -d | identify - 
    done
```

It's awfully slow for larger files, though, since the shell can't know if something inside the loop is going to read the pipe, and so `read` needs to read byte-by-byte. This should probably be implemented in Perl or some other real programming language so that buffering could be controlled exactly.

Answer (score 1):

> Even if I separate the files with `\004` before sending them to `stdout` ...

Good thing you can modify the sending procedure. My solution is as follows:

```
for f in *.jpg; do echo S; base64 "$f"; echo ""; done |
# the above is just an example sending process
while read dummy; do
  sed -u '/^$/q' | base64 -d | identify -
done
```

Clarification:

- Single "file block" starts with an expendable line ("S" in this case) that carries no data. If `read` cannot find a line, the whole command ends.
- `sed` passes data to decoder until there's an empty line (note: additional empty line doesn't change the output of `base64 -d`).
- It's crucial to use unbuffered `sed` (`-u` flag); otherwise one `sed` could read too much and eventually discard what it thinks is excessive data; then the next `sed` (consequently the next `identify`) wouldn't get all the data it should.

Hints:

- The extra line can carry metadata instead of "S", like a filename or so (but beware of newlines in names etc.).
- Because `base64` produces bigger output than its input, you may want to use `gzip` on the both sides, especially if your stream travels via the Internet.